# How to install latest version of fontawesome using npm in react js?

Tags: reactjs, npm, font-awesome-5

I want to use the latest fontawesome version. but i cannot install using npm. How to install the fontawesome latest version(5.0.10) using npm?

I tried like this
**`npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome`**

Answer (score 0):

It will always install latest version by default. However you can force package manager to install specified version too.

Just run

`npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome@5.0.10 --save`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `--save` for it to also show up in package.json

or by using yarn

`yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome@latest`

Answer (score 0):

just use this command

```
npm i fontawesome@5.0.10 --save
```

You need to add --save for it to also show up in package.json

Answer (score 0):

We are actually at 5.0.13 as of today. We also have some pre-release files for 5.1 that improve things quite a bit.

You can install the pre-release version like this:

`npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

If you are a [Pro](https://fontawesome.com) subscriber and you've configured NPM to use our private NPM repository you can do this:

`npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro`

And finally if you want to install the latest 5.0.x version:

`npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts`

or

`npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webfonts`

Also note that everything that comes from Font Awesome officially will be under the [@fortawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=scope%3Afortawesome) scope.